# Azure addon - accessing WADPerformanceCountersTable?

Tags: azure

If I write an Azure addon, can it access the WADPerformanceCountersTable table (of the business application that provisioned this addon)? Especially in terms of security/permissions.

E.g. say I wanted my addon to monitor some performance counters, and send an email alert if they pass some thresholds (regardless of whether there  are already such commercial products, I'm just interested in the technical capability). What will I have to do? I'm guessing WADPerformanceCountersTable isn't publicly exposed to the entire worlds - so how can I make them accessible to my addon?

thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

`WADPerformanceCountersTable` is nothing different from other Azure tables, and it's stored in the storage defined by `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString` in the configuration file. You will need the storage account name/key pair to read from this table.

FYI, here is an article about how to effectively fetching performance counter data from this table: http://gauravmantri.com/2012/02/17/effective-way-of-fetching-diagnostics-data-from-windows-azure-diagnostics-table-hint-use-partitionkey/